# Generic OrderBy Function

Tags: vb.net, linq, sql-order-by

I have a grid view with a lot of columns, all need to be sorted on. I have seen a few snippets out there, but I cannot get any of them to work with my example. Here is what I have so far.

```
  Protected Sub gvSearch_OnSorting(ByVal sender As Object, _
                                   ByVal e As GridViewSortEventArgs)

    If Not Session("sort") Is Nothing Then
        Dim strView = Session("sort").ToString()
        gvSearch.DataSource = ApplySorting(Session("grid"), , "ASC")
    End If
End Sub
```

I found this in a post, but I am not sure what to put in as the Expression

```
Private Function ApplySorting(Of T, U)( _
    query As IQueryable(Of T), _
    predicate As Expression(Of Func(Of T, U)), _
    order As String) As IQueryable(Of T)

    Dim ordered = TryCast(Query, IOrderedQueryable(Of T))
    If order = "ASC" Then
        If ordered IsNot Nothing Then
            Return ordered.ThenBy(predicate)
        End If
        Return query.OrderBy(predicate)
    Else
        If ordered IsNot Nothing Then
            Return ordered.ThenByDescending(predicate)
        End If
        Return query.OrderByDescending(predicate)
    End If
End Function
```

End Class

I know that the actual order would look like

```
Dim GridValues As List(Of spSearchResult2Result)
GridValues = db.spSearchResult2().ToList()
GridValues.OrderBy(Function(x) x.CreateUserID)
```

The call into ApplySorting would contain e.SortExpression, but I do not know how to get it in there. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The expression is

```
Function(x) x.CreateUserID
```

---

```
gvSearch.DataSource = _
    ApplySorting(Session("grid"), Function(x) x.CreateUserID, "ASC")
```

Comment: Would intellisense pick that up? when I put that in, there are no properties of x there

Comment: `Session("grid")` returns an `object` making it impossible for intellisense to guess the members of `x`. Try to use `DirectCast(Session("grid"), TypeOfYourGrid)`.

Comment: Still nothing, I have this
Dim grid As List(Of spSearchResult2Result) = DirectCast(Session("grid"), List(Of spSearchResult2Result))
gvSearch.DataSource = ApplySorting(grid, Function(x) x. , "ASC")
still no intellisense

Comment: It is always the compiler, which decides if an expression is OK, not intellisense. Sometimes intellisense just fails. I am not sure if your types are OK. The first parameter must be a `IQueryable(Of T)`. A `List(Of T)` is not a `IQueryable(Of T)'.

Comment: By the way, the purpose of `ApplySorting` is not to sort data, but to append a term to a query, so passing it as `List(Of something)` won't work!